# Cannot connect to database during umbraco install

Tags: database, umbraco7

I have a clean project, which i am trying to get started. I have also created a clean database.

Both are running locally on my pc.

I can connect to my database with linqpad, with no issues. 
But when i try to "customize" and set a microsoft SQL server, it says

`Could not connect to database`

And in console, i get a 500 internal server error, on :

```
:62164/install/api/PostValidateDatabaseConnection
```

What can i do ?

**Edit**
when trying to use a custom connection string, i get this :

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController.ExecuteStep(InstallSetupStep step, JToken instruction)
 2017-09-12 09:16:22,389 [P1996/D2/T11] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Step completed (took 32ms)
 2017-09-12 09:16:22,390 [P1996/D2/T11] ERROR Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - An error occurred during installation step DatabaseConfigure
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Umbraco.Core.DatabaseContext.SaveConnectionString(String connectionString, String providerName)
   at Umbraco.Core.DatabaseContext.ConfigureDatabaseConnection(String connectionString)
   at Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallSteps.DatabaseConfigureStep.ConfigureConnection(DatabaseModel database)
   at Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallSteps.DatabaseConfigureStep.Execute(DatabaseModel database)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Have you tried with a custom connection string? If yes can you paste it here?

Comment: i haven't, and i do not currently know how the format of the string should be ?

Comment: which db server are  you using? this is an example of a connection string for sqlexpress: server=127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;database=YOURDB;user id=YOURUSERID;password='YOURPASSWORD'

Comment: it is a database made locally in microsoft sql server management studio 17, this would be the connection string i quess: server=DESKTOP-GR1B3N9\SQLEXPRESS ;database=Adventurelrp_Website ;user id=adventurelrp_user_login ;password='YOURPASSWORD'

Comment: ok have you tried using this custom string during the umbraco install?

Comment: @Eyescream i get an exception, this :  look at edit in the post.

Comment: sorry I have no idea, that's really strange.. have you tried to reinstall it from scratch?

Comment: @Eyescream and that worked... why i really have no idea!... reinstall and then it was able to boot up.. If you want to add that as an answer, i can set that for the answer for the question

Comment: Nice! Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, even with a custom connection string, you still get a 500 error I think that you have a botched installation and you should try to reinstall Umbraco from scratch